# How do I make a easy print out (overview like excel) in SharePoint?

Tags: excel, list-view, list

If we use action items for projects/meetings and we want to make an easy print overview, this seems to be impossible. Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I went a slightly different route.  I created a httpmodule that checks if the querystring "PrinterFriendly" is true and if so, it uses an alternate masterpage which I created specifically for printing.

```
class PrinterFriendlyMasterPage : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(PrinterFriendlyMasterPage_PreRequestHandlerExecute);
    }

    void PrinterFriendlyMasterPage_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
        if (page == null) return;

        //Code taken from:  http://www.pings.dk/blog/archive/tags/Master%20page/default.aspx
        // If the request originates from a Publishing Page then we have to
        // change the master page on the current Sharepoint Web instance object
        // (of course we don't want to persist this change since it would
        // change the master page permanently..for all users).

        if (page is PublishingLayoutPage || page is TemplateRedirectionPage)
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

            if (ShouldOverrideMasterPage(context))
            {
                SPContext.Current.Web.MasterUrl = Properties.Settings.Default.PrinterFriendlyMasterPage_MasterPageUrl;
                SPContext.Current.Web.CustomMasterUrl = Properties.Settings.Default.PrinterFriendlyMasterPage_MasterPageUrl;
                page.Load += new EventHandler(application_page_Load);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Now, if this is a normal wss 3.0 page hook into
            // the PreInit event (just before the ordinary Page event
            // cycle starts.            
            page.PreInit += new EventHandler(PrinterFriendlyMasterPage_PreInit);
        }
    }

    void PrinterFriendlyMasterPage_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Page page = sender as Page;
            if (page == null) return;
            if (page.MasterPageFile == null) return;

            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

            if (ShouldOverrideMasterPage(context))
            {
                page.MasterPageFile = Properties.Settings.Default.PrinterFriendlyMasterPage_MasterPageUrl;
                page.Load += new EventHandler(application_page_Load);
            }

        }
        catch { }
    }

    private bool ShouldOverrideMasterPage(HttpContext context)
    {
        return GetQueryStringSwitch(context, Properties.Settings.Default.PrinterFriendlyMasterPage_QueryString);
    }

    private bool GetQueryStringSwitch(HttpContext context, string queryString)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.QueryString[queryString]) &&
                Boolean.Parse(context.Request.QueryString[queryString]))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch { }
        return false;
    }

    private bool ShouldShowQuickLaunch(HttpContext context)
    {
        return GetQueryStringSwitch(context, Properties.Settings.Default.PrinterFriendlyMasterPage_LeftNavQueryString);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    void application_page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page page = sender as Page;
        if (page == null) return;

        try
        {

            HtmlTableCell leftNavCell = page.Master.FindControl("LeftNavCell") as HtmlTableCell;
            if (ShouldShowQuickLaunch(HttpContext.Current))
            {
                leftNavCell.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                leftNavCell.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on a few dozen Task/Project Tracking systems over the years.  I normally try and provide good working views that can be used to conduct the meeting (via a computer).  For the most part I try and stay away from printing since it is a waste of paper.

In the cases where they need printing, there are a number of tricks that can be used to grab the content of a list view or web part and send it to a pop-up window without the surrounding formatting for easier printing.

While I developed my own script years ago, here is a some easy to follow info available online:  http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2009/04/06/jquery-for-everyone-print-any-web-parts-plugin/